# select with exceptional case count = 0 and registers = 1

Tags: select, count, inner-join

Works fine:

```
SELECT  m.*, i.description
FROM mac_address_gt m
INNER JOIN int_gt i ON m.ip = i.ip AND m.interface = i.interface
WHERE m.mac = ? AND m.count > 0 AND m.vlan = ?
ORDER BY m.count asc
```

But there is one exceptional case, where if the m.count = 0 and the number of returned registers = 1, I must show it.

Comment: It works, but it doesn't work? And what does "show it" mean? This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Hi friend, sorry for my poor english. The sentece works fine, but because the complex of the networking information stored in the db,  I need  one exception, if you look m.count>0 is a filter and returns registers only when m.count is gretan than zero until here everything is ok.  But if the next condition appears  m.count is equal 0 and the numbers of return registers is exactly 1, then I need to show the result too. The normal behavior is that returns many registers and the field count of each register is > 0.

Comment: nelson I have written an answer, but to me it is unclear what the number of registers is in your case, as you did not specify this in the question. Please provide more information, so I can edit my answer and improve it in light of the information you provide.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. PS Your comments are very unclear. Please take your time & refer to everything that you need to & use more words & don't try to cram everything into one sentence. The problem is not the English, the problem is not saying everything that is relevant & not presenting in small steps.--See my 1st comment. And a [mre] is obligatory but you have given neither appropriate code+data nor appropriate explanation for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point it is unclear what the number of registers is in your case, so this answer will only focus on how the query should be changed. A possible resulting query could look like

```
SELECT  m.*, i.description
FROM mac_address_gt m
INNER JOIN int_gt i ON m.ip = i.ip AND m.interface = i.interface
WHERE m.mac = ? AND ((m.count > 0) OR ((m.count) AND (<number of returned registers criteria>))) AND m.vlan = ?
ORDER BY m.count asc
```

The `<number of returned registers criteria>` is up to you to implement. Also, if the number of returned registers happens to be `m.vlan` or `m.mac`, then you will need to restructure your query.

EDIT

In light of the query given in the comment section this is how the query can be rewritten:

```
SELECT m.*, i.description 
FROM mac_address_hn m 
INNER JOIN int_hn i 
ON m.ip = i.ip AND 
   m.interface = i.interface 
JOIN (SELECT COUNT(m.count) as cnt FROM mac_address_hn m INNER JOIN int_hn i ON m.ip = i.ip AND m.interface = i.interface WHERE m.mac = "78d3.47a3.5b78" AND m.vlan = "4010") mycount
ON 1=1
WHERE  m.mac = "78d3.47a3.5b78" AND 
       m.vlan = "4010" AND 
       (((count = 0) and (mycount.cnt = 1)) or
        ((count > 0) and (mycount.cnt > 0))
       );
```

Comment: I got it but I dont know how to optimized  and insert de parametrized  variables, because I am using this sentece from a controller in laravel.

Comment: SELECT  m.*, i.description FROM mac_address_hn m INNER JOIN int_hn i ON m.ip = i.ip AND m.interface = i.interface
WHERE m.mac = "78d3.47a3.5b78"  AND m.vlan = "4010" AND (
   (count = 0 AND (SELECT COUNT(m.count) FROM mac_address_hn m INNER JOIN int_hn i ON m.ip = i.ip AND m.interface = i.interface
WHERE m.mac = "78d3.47a3.5b78"  AND m.vlan = "4010" ) = 1)
OR (count > 0 AND (SELECT COUNT(m.count) FROM mac_address_hn m INNER JOIN int_hn i ON m.ip = i.ip AND m.interface = i.interface
WHERE m.mac = "78d3.47a3.5b78"  AND m.vlan = "4010" ) > 0))
ORDER BY m.count asc

Comment: the requirements are :    select etc, from etc where etc and ( (count = 0  and numofregisters  = 1) or ( count > 0 and numberofregisters > 0))

Comment: @nelsonavalos I see. I have edited my answer, take a look at the last join, where the aggregation calculation is considered to be a table called `mycount` with a single field called `cnt` and a single record in its result, joined on the criteria of 1=1. Later on `mycount.cnt` can be used similarly to the way you are using any other field.